# How to convert xls files to xlsx files and save in a folder using SSIS?

Tags: ssis

How to convert .xls file to .xlsx file in ssis.
My requirement is to export the user defined stored procedure in to excel destination. 
This is my control flow task:

> [Execute SQL Task (Drop excel table)]-->[Execute SQL Task (create
>   excel table)]-->[Data flow Task]

My Data flow task is :

> [OLEDB Source (to execute the stored procedure)]-->[Data
>   conversion(convert to unicode)]--> [Excel Destination]

When I do this, the excel destination table is stored as .xls file. I need to convert to .xlsx file. I have excel 2013 installed on my server but file saved as .xls. Please help me to write a code to convert xls files to xlsx file using SSIS.

Thank you for your time and help !

Comment: Why not change Excel Connection Manager by choosing Microsoft Excel 2007? In this way you can use an .xlsx file..

Comment: I chose Microsoft Excel 2007. But is saving as .xls file

Comment: When you create excel table (Execute SQL Task) the name of the file is provided dinamically using Expression and variables?

Comment: I did not use expression and variables . In the first execute sql task, I dropped the table then I create the excel table again to ensure that the stored procedure result are not appending. I want to rewrite the excel table every time I execute the package. This is the link I referred https://dwhanalytics.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/ssis-dynamically-generate-excel-tablesheet/#comment-7392

Comment: Ok, just change your Excel Connection Manager to Microsoft Excel 2007 and pointing it to a real xlsx file (you can add before  your table to this file manually using same name and same path but different extension).  Now the two Execute Sql Task should recognise xlsx file. Create it and then verify mapping columns in Data Flow Task

Comment: I read that SSIS cannot connect to an xlsx file using excel connection manager.   https://dataintegrity.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/xlsx/

Comment: Are you using SSDT 2013? My suggestion would be of help..did you try?

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2013 shell integrated

Comment: Thanks alex. it helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which version of data tool are you using? SSDT or BIDS?

If you are using SSDT, like Alex said, you can choose excel 2007 in the EXCEL destination and save the file as .xlsx.
[image]

If you are using BIDS before SS 2005, you can try to use OLE DB destination and create a new connection manager through Native OLE DB\Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider.
[image]

Comment: I am using visual studio data tool 2013

Comment: then go for the excel destination way. I already edited the answer.